# How to restore $PATH environment variable?

Tags: 12.10, environment-variables

I did this in the console:

```
unset PATH
```

After this I started getting this error:

```
grep: command not found
```

Is there any easy way to get all environment variables back?

Answer (score 6):

Variables unseted like that are only effective in your current shell and any child processes. If you didn't save those commands in your profile or shell-rc file, any new shells that get started up should have the original value again.

Closing your current shell ([terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal)) and starting up a new one is the simplest way to get  $PATH variable back.

Comment: wow you saved me a lot of time.. I too messed up the PATH by not adding :$PATH and simply did an export..  i was digging to recover.. but simply closing the terminal saved the trouble.. !

Comment: You save me. <3

Answer (score 1):

You could try to resource your .bashrc (or .cshrc) or your .login if PATH is modified at all there.

There are a few files in /etc that deal with PATH, grepping my particular system shows /etc/environment to probably be your best bet, which for me has a line `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games"`