# Regarding command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I am facing issues with linux command execution:

```
root@PGStaging:/etc# ls
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
root@PGStaging:~# ps
Command 'ps' is available in '/bin/ps'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ps: command not found
```

How to solve above issues?

Answer (score 1):

I have never faced this problem before, so I really don't know if this will work or not. Try this: Go to your home directory, there you can find a file named `.bashrc` (it is a hidden file, so enable 'show hidden files' in your file explorer for convenience).
Open the file with a text editor. Then, at the end of the file, add this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin
```

In theory, this will add `/bin` to your `PATH` variable.
Then save the file. I hope this works. Good luck.

Comment: still i am facing the issue echo $PATH
/opt/2ndQuadrant/PostgreSQL/11/lib::/usr/bin

Comment: You (or the program you installed outside of the software repositories) have changed the system path. You will need to restore that. See the duplicate on how to change the system path.

Comment: how to restore system path in linux

Comment: i  am working on prod server

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I found this link:  https://askubuntu.com/a/291816/929226 Accourding to this, open `.bashrc` file, and add `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games"` to the end of the file and see what happens